# Type of Iqueryable at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, iqueryable

I have a method which returns Iqueryable result, but the result is based on an if else condition, where if condition satisfies then I will use "AssetDetails" class object ,otherwise "UserandClientdetails" object.
 Here is the code:

```
  private IQueryable<?> GetAssetDetails(ShareViewModel item)
                {
             ...
              if (type == "Video")
                    {
    if (type == "Video")
                    {
                    return from meta in my.Assets().OfType<Model.Video>()
                           join content in my.Contents() on meta.ContentId equals content.ID
                           join channel in my.Channels() on content.ChannelId equals channel.ID
                           where meta.ID == item.ID
                           select new AssetDetails
                           {
                               ContentTitle = content.Title,
                               ChannelName = channel.ChannelName,
                               ...
                           };
                      }
                else
    {  return from meta in my.Assets().OfType<Model.Client>()
                           join country in db.Countries on meta.ResellerCountry equals country.ID                       
                           where meta.ID == item.ID
                           select new UserAndClientDetails
                           {
                               Name = meta.ResellerName,
                               UserName = meta.ResellerEmail,
                               ..



   };}
```

So how to decide type of Iqueyable here at runtime??

Comment: Take Entity Framework out of the picture. What would you do if you had a method that took two paths that returned completely different things?

Comment: You can try simply returning `IQueryable` instead of the generic `IQueryable<>`.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to verify that this works, so I'll go ahead and post it as an answer.

You can return `IQueryable` instead of the generic `IQueryable<>`. That will accept any `IQueryable<T>`. However, `IQueryable`, since it has no direct inner type, is *very* limited. So, you'll still likely need to cast to `IQueryable<>` at some other point in your code to get anything done:

```
// Piece of code where you know you are working with `IQueryable<AssetDetails>`
IQueryable<AssetDetails> assetDetails = GetAssetDetails(someItem);
```

That's a little dangerous, though, as you're assuming that your code is working perfectly and the right type of thing is being returned. Better would be:

```
try
{
    var assetDetails = (IQueryable<AssetDetails>)GetAssetDetails(someItem);
    // do something with `assetDetails`
}
catch (InvalidCastException)
{  
    // recover gracefully
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a base class ?

```
public abstract class BaseDetails
{
    // ...
}

public class AssetDetails : BaseDetails
{
    // ...
}
public class UserAndClientDetails: BaseDetails
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you method would be like :

```
private IQueryable<BaseDetails> GetAssetDetails(ShareViewModel item)
{
    // return either IQueryable<AssetDetails> or IQueryable<UserAndClientDetails>
}
```

Comment: Could be wrong, but off the top of my head, I don't think that will actually work. This is a problem with covariance -- an `IQueryable<AssetDetails>` is not a type of `IQueryable<BaseDetails>` even though `AssetDetails` is a type of `BaseDetails`.

Comment: You're right. I just tested it, and it works fine. Sorry about that.